# Android, NullPointerException on method with SQLite command in Service

Tags: android, sqlite, service

only one task, why is my sqlite commands in methods, when iam calling it from service writing me a nullpointerexception ? ... When i try use toast, it work perfectly, but after i use mDbHelper.open/naplnSviatky/close, my app will crash.

That methods have only query commands, and in activities and fragments work ok

Here's my `service`

```
public class SviatokFullFillService extends Service 
{
String username;
private DatabaseOp mDbHelper;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    username = sharedPrefs.getString("prefUsername", "NULL");

    //Toast.makeText(this, username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mDbHelper.open();
    mDbHelper.naplnSviatky(username);
    mDbHelper.close();
}

}
```

Here's my `LogCat`

```
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service sk.tomino.studentDiary.SviatokFullFillService@410f1188 with Intent { cmp=sk.tomino.studentDiary/.SviatokFullFillService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2950)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at sk.tomino.studentDiary.SviatokFullFillService.onStart(SviatokFullFillService.java:30)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2916)
04-22 14:16:43.890: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Please upload the code of `DatabaseOp` class

Comment: You might want to learn how to run your app in debug mode, and set breakpoints in the code to examine the values of variables.

Comment: Initialize mDbHelper before using.

Answer (score 1):

You have declare variable `private DatabaseOp mDbHelper;` at class level but when you are using it in `onStart()` method, you haven't initialize it, hence it is throwing `NullPointerException`

Comment: ok thanks, i forgot on it ... and please, can you help me with playing naplnSviatok method on background, after i start it, my mainthread will wait and freeze app, i need start this method and gui going next

Comment: @Tomino, where is that method ?

Comment: @Tomino, Lets see, please upload it's code in the question.